# How to convert each pair of list into tuple in python

Tags: python, list, tuples, zip

I want to convert `list = [1,4,2,3,0]` to `list_tup = [(1,4),(4,2),(2,3),(3,0)]`. You can see my code below but it outputs `[(1,4),(2,3)]`. I am wondering how to adjust indices in zip.

```
list=[1,4,2,3,0]
list_tup = tuple(zip(list[0::2], list[1::2]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try zipping the whole list with the list without the first element:

```
l = [1,4,2,3,0]
print(list(zip(l, l[1:])))
```

Or use unpack `*`:

```
l = [1,4,2,3,0]
print([*zip(l, l[1:])])
```

They both output:

```
[(1, 4), (4, 2), (2, 3), (3, 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Zipping whole list without first element of the list

l = [1,4,2,3,0]
print(list(zip(l, l[1:])))

output:

[(1, 4), (4, 2), (2, 3), (3, 0)]